# Building dynamic lambda predicate with short date

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, predicatebuilder, predicates

I have the following code that helps me build a lambda expression via reflection. However when I try to compare versus a `Date` it converts my value to a full `DateTime` stamp. How can I get it to build my predicate so it will only compare the short date?

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(property);
Type propertyType = propInfo.PropertyType;
if (Utilities.IsNullableType(propertyType))
{
    propertyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
}
ParameterExpression propAlias = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), alias);
MemberExpression left = Expression.Property(propAlias, property);
ConstantExpression right = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType));
BinaryExpression comparer = BuildComparisonExpression(left, right, comparison);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(comparer, propAlias);
```

I know it's the `Convert.ChangeType` that is converting the string to a `DateTime`, but what I get back is `item => item.DateToCheck == 1/1/2012 12:00:00AM`, when I want `item => item.DateToCheck == 1/1/2012`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass `Convert.ChangeType(...)` a third argument, the already existing `IFormatProvider` for this exact purpose: `DateTimeFormatInfo`.